# Create a code with a letter and a number two for-loops

Tags: java

I wanna generate 743 different "codes" which should follow the following syntax: `A1,A2,...,A20,B1,B2...` So I thought about doing it with two for-loops.

- One that goes through every "row" which is A,B,C,...
- and the second one that goes through every "column" which  is 1-20.

Afterwards I wanna connect them and that's going to lead to one code which is "A1" for example.

My problem is the first loop, how do I do it that hes going to add an A at the first iteration, a B at the second iteration etc...

Comment: use a `char` equal to `'A'` and increment that `char` step by step.

Comment: 20x26=520 ... that's less than 743. Just wondering...

Comment: Ye true, 20 was just an example, i can take a higher number and thats going to be fine then

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: you just have to use a `char` datatype. Below is the complete code.

```
for(char ch='A';ch<='Z';ch++)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ch+""+i); // this will concatenate ch and i
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know that you could do "ch++" with a character. Thought its only possible with numbers.

Comment: When i started with java it was also unknown to me now i and you both know it.

Comment: To some extent `char`s *are* numbers. "A" is just a representation you get for e.g. 0x41 (in ASCII).